# angular model data value not coming to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular material for displaying **modal dialog**. but i am facing issues with getting the input field value to controller.

```
console.log($scope.aadharNumber);
```

In the console, i am getting 'undefined' message.

### controller

```
$scope.showModal = function(viewName, ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
          controller: DialogController,
          templateUrl: 'views/'+viewName,
          targetEvent: ev,
          scope: $scope
        })
        .then(function(modal) {              
        });
      };
```

### view

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_email_24px.svg" class=""></md-icon>
    <input ng-model="aadharNumber" name="aadharno" type="text" placeholder="AADHAAR Number" required style="text-align:left">                           
    </div>

</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coming as undefined because , its not defined in the controller. If you want to see the changes u can use `$watch` to get the updated value of the model in your controller.

```
$scope.$watch('aadharNumber',function(){
 console.log($scope.aadharNumber);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the variable "aadharNumber" in your controller first.

```
$scope.aadharNumber = "";
```

Then in your view put: (the same as before)

```
<input ng-model="aadharNumber" name="aadharno" type="text"     placeholder="AADHAAR Number" required style="text-align:left">
```

EDIT:
Like dimitris said. I forgot to mention you can Watch the variable with Angular. It's some sort of "onchange".

Here is his code:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.aadharNumber,function(){
console.log("$scope.aadharNumber has changed into: " + $scope.aadharNumber);
})
```

Comment: i am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

Jelmer's answer is almost there but I think the completely correct approach is a combination of answers given so far

In controller initialize your ng-model

```
$scope.aadharNumber = "";
```

Then in view leave it as you had it:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_email_24px.svg" class=""></md-icon>
    <input ng-model="aadharNumber" name="aadharno" type="text" placeholder="AADHAAR Number" required style="text-align:left">                           
</div>
</md-input-container>
```

If you want to get the value from the input (which I'm pretty sure you do) then you have to indeed use $watch as shushanth p said:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.aadharNumber,function(){
    console.log("$scope.aadharNumber has changed into: " + $scope.aadharNumber);
})
```